# Parametrization of a Complex Path/Contour Integration

Tags: contour-integration, parametric

How would I parametrize the path which is a straight line from 1 to a complex point z?  Does $\delta (t) = z^t$ make any sense?

Comment: How about $\delta(t) = 1-t + z t$ for $t \in [0,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z_0$ and $z_1$ are points in the complex plane, then $\delta(t)=(1-t)z_0 + t \, z_1$ is called a *convex combination* or, sometimes, a *weighted average* of the points.  When $t=0$, $\delta(0)=z_0$ and when $t=1$, $\delta(1)=z_1$.  For $0<t<1$, $\delta(t)$ lies on the line segment between $z_0$ and $z_1$ - that's rather the point of the weighted average business.  As $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, the point $\delta(t)$ moves from $z_0$ to $z_1$ tracing out that segment.

If $z_0=1$ and $z_1 = -1+i$, we get $\delta(t)=(1-t)+t\,(-1+i)$.  The corresponding motion looks like so:

[image]